# Why are justify-items and justify-self invalid syntax in Sublime?

Tags: css, sublimetext3, css-grid

It appears that the `justify-items` and `justify-self` properties aren't recognized by Sublime Text & simply show up as invalid syntax. (Sublime is up-to-date, the language is set to CSS, and justify-items and justify-self are used correctly in regards to parent/child grid relationship).

Note: I don't have any syntax issues with similar properties like `justify-content` or `align-items`; only `justify-items` and `justify-self`.

Any ideas as to why this is happening?

--

Here's an image of what I'm seeing:

[image: Code Snippet Text Editor Screen Shot]

And here's the code:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, minmax(150px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 20px;
  justify-items: center;
}

.item {
  justify-self: end;
}
```

Comment: only a sublime developer can help you ... this is very common as issue when new properties aren't still supported

Comment: It could be that these properties are still in Working Draft state in their spec (CSS Box Align Module 3) and thus not "official" properties yet. The other properties you used and mentioned are all in Candidate Recommendation stage (official).

Comment: But are the properties actually working? I often see properties with invalid highlighting in IDEs, such as jsFiddle. However, they still work in the browser.

Comment: Seeing things not syntax highlight as you would expect in Sublime is due to the syntax specification in Sublime not recognizing that item as valid. That means that in this case those properties aren't known to the syntax so they don't highlight. This doesn't have any effect on the file when it's used; it's purely a visual thing.

Answer (score 2):

Install the CSS3 package: https://packagecontrol.io/packages/CSS3

`Cltr+Shift+P`, choose `Package Control Install Package`, choose `CSS3`.

Then set `CSS3` as the default syntax for all `.css` files in `Views -> Syntax`.